# Using jQuery plugin as Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use a jQuery plugin that can curve text (Arctext.js) as an Angular Directive.

The Directive seems to work fine, the given text is curved as expected, except that I want this text to be an Angular variable.
And the problem is the jQuery plugin seems to be executed before Angular resolves the variable value.

My html element :

```
<h2 class="circle">{{ myController.myVar }}</h2>
```

My directive :

```
return {
    restrict: "C",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.arctext({radius: 500})
    }
}
```

The page displays '{{ myController.myVar }}' as curved text.

How to get the variable value instead ?

Comment: Will you share more code or prepare a fiddle?

Comment: looks like your directive is not able to access plugin. Did you try to get plugin data inside directive.?

Comment: Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/k8ffmbL0/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<h2 class="circle" text="{{ myController.myVar }}"></h2>
```

Directive:

```
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('text', function(newval) {
            if (newval) {
                $(element).text(newval).arctext({radius: 500})
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The title is not showing. I suppose the arctext plugin use the .text() method to get the string inside element. How to apply the plugin to the 'text' attribute in your example ?

Comment: @BenjaminLemoine I update the answer. see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvqgfkyc/)

Comment: Ok but it doesn't work on my project. I don't know why...
When the page is loading for the first time (ie: refresh button) the title appears correctly but not curved (like if the plugin is not instanced).
If I click on a link and then I go back to this page, the title is correctly displayed and curved. It's like, at the first time, the plugin is not initialized yet. I can't reproduce the problem on fiddle...

Comment: The $observe element was fired twice.
Testing if the attribute value is not empty before using the jQuery function solved my problem.